# compare 2 sheets (very big) in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to compare 2 sheets, each sheet has 1 column with id numbers.

there is a difference of 30 rows between the sheets.

sheet 2 is the biggest.

I want to find the 30 rows which not appear in sheet 1,

how should I find it with vlookup?

thank you in advance

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Consider Index & match instead of vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IDs on Sheet2 are in column A (with a header in Row 1), try this formula in cell B2 and copy it down your range:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,SHEET1!$A$2:$A$1000,1,FALSE)),1,0)
```

You will need to change $A$1000 to the last cell in your range on Sheet1.  The 1's will be the 30 missing rows, which you can now filter on.